# Learning mathematical markup: popups

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

Maybe it would be useful to make pop-ups with raw code, when cursor is hovering a formula? It would be quite useful for those who just learn MathJax. It's annoying to click "edit" each time to find out how the author writes expressions. Of course, popups should not appear too fast, and users should be able to disable them. Do you like the idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is sort-of already implemented via the [MathJax Contextual Menu](http://www.mathjax.org/help-v2/menu/).

Comment: Or in other words, "right click on MathJax expression" -> "Select 'Show Math As' -> TeX commands".